# Appending in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, class, dictionary

Appending in python issue:

```
   #other code irrelevant to q
        if #code:
            key3_lst = key3_lst.append(b.month)
            b_w_dic[key3] = key3_lst
        if  #code:
            key4_lst = key4_lst.append(b.month)
            b_w_dic[key4] = key4_lst
    return b_w_dic
```

I get an error saying that in key3_lst = key3_lst.append(b.month) builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
key3_lst = key3_lst.append(b.month)
```

the "append" function is just that, a function,  with the return type of "None"

just use:

```
key3_lst.append(b.month)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the question to just have that one line since all the rest is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You don't append and set it to a variable. Instead of `key3_lst = key3_lst.append(b.month)` which will make `key3_lst` = `None` just append without giving it a variable `key3_lst.append(b.month)`

Answer (score 0):

The append method applies the changes in place and returns None.

```
>>> data = [0, 1, 2 ,3]
>>> data
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> data.append(4)
>>> data
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> data = data.append(5)
>>> type(data)
<class 'NoneType'>
```